# A way to get names from ids when in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, cascading

So I have 3 cascading drop down lists - Brand, Year and Model. And I have a Boat model.But boat model is not associated with the 3 cascading drop downs. User selects drop downs and rails `#create` the boat. The problem is I have the ids of the drop down selected items. My `#create` is;

```
def create
   @boat = current_user.boats.new(boat_params) if logged_in?
    if @boat.save
      flash[:success] = "Boat created!"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end
```

and `boat_params`

```
    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model)
    end
```

When I click next button it saves the ids it is because of the #create action i believe.

Here is `#new.html`

```
<% provide(:title, 'List My Boat') %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@boat) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Brand %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:brand,  Brand.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'}) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Year %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:year, Year.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Year"}, {:id => 'years_select'}) %>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Model %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:model, Model.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Model"}, {:id => 'models_select'}) %>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
     </div>
    <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#brands_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_years_path %>",
        data: {
          brand_id : $('#brands_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
    $('#years_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_models_path %>",
        data: {
          year_id : $('#years_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the full `#boats controller`

```
class BoatsController < ApplicationController


  def new
    @boat = Boat.new
  end

  def create
   @boat = current_user.boats.new(boat_params) if logged_in?
    if @boat.save
      flash[:success] = "Boat created!"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def show
  end


  def edit
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
  end


  def update_years
    # updates year and model based on brand selected
    brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
    @years = brand.years.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Year")
    @models   = brand.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Model")
  end

  def update_models
    # updates model based on year selected
    year = Year.find(params[:year_id])
    @models = year.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Model")
  end

private

    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model)
    end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `f.collection_select(...)` takes `:id` as key for brand, model and year. If you insist on using `:name` as a key try this:

```
f.collection_select(:brand,  Brand.all, :name, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'})
```

Comment: Thank you i tried this for brand year and model, but when i change :id to :name for 3 of them. Model drop down is not updated. It still takes the id. Do you think is it because year table has year name and brand_id?. Maybe i should include model_id as well?.

Comment: And sorry what do you mean by changing column types in boat table? They are string

Comment: Oh, never mind. I thought they are integers. What do you mean "model drop down is not updated"? Are there any items inside drop-down list or it's empty? Show us the markup rendered for select field.

Comment: Hello Andrey, when I put name attributes to update_models and update_years method it worked. Thank you for your time